# Test for equality of lines, simple regression

Tags: regression, t-test

I have two data sets with the same predictor and response and I want to obtain a p-value that they follow the same regression model $E(y)=ax+c$. Sample sizes are different.

What test should I use? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you specifying that it should be a t-test in your title (and tags)?

Comment: Good point. Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two data sets with the same predictor and response and I want to obtain a p-value that they follow the same regression model y=ax+c. Sample sizes are different. What test should I use?

There are a number of ways to approach this. If you believe they should have the same variation about the model as well, you can stack up the $y$-variable for the two data sets and the $x$-variable for the two data sets, then add a 'group' indicator, $g$ (0 for data set 1, 1 for data set 2, say), and an interaction between group and x-variable.

You regress (via multiple regression)  $y$ on $x$, $g$ and $x\times g$

You could either test the interaction term (which is a test of the same slope) or the group and interaction variables (via an F test) - a test of whether the two lines are coincident.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not at all clear to me what you mean here. What's "a power test"? You *can't* actually show they're the same. Are you talking about something like an *equivalence test*?

Comment: No, a hypothesis test *doesn't* tell you the probability the two lines are the same.